# Prove that measures on intersections =0

Tags: measure-theory

I am stuck with a rather pesky problem. I have to prove that for the measure space $(X,\mathcal{A}, \mu)$    $A_1,A_2.....\in \mathcal{A}$, $$\mu \left(\bigcap_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j\right)=0$$ and $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mu \left(\bigcap_{j=1}^{n}A_j\right)=0$$

It is given that $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\mu (A_j) <\infty$$
I don't quite know how to approach this. I am guessing that it probably has something to do with continuity from above, but I can't really use this as I have no other info on the $A_j$'s except they're all part of $\mathcal{A}$.

Some thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: This is not true when all $A_i$ are equal to the same set $A \in \mathcal{A}$ with nonzero measure.

Comment: The statement should be : If $\mu \left(\bigcap_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j\right)=0$ and moreover, if $\mu \left(\bigcap_{j=1}^{n}A_j\right)< \infty$ for some $n$ then $\lim_n \mu \left(\bigcap_{j=1}^{n}A_j\right) = 0$.

Comment: That is not what the problem reads, though. I have to prove $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ first, it seems.

Answer (score 4):

From $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\mu\left(A_{j}\right)<\infty$ it follows
directly that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu\left(A_{n}\right)=0$.

This combined with $\bigcap_{j=1}^{n}A_{j}\subseteq A_{n}$ and consequently $\mu\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^{n}A_{j}\right)\leq\mu\left(A_{n}\right)$ tells
us that: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^{n}A_{j}\right)=0$$

We have $\bigcap_{j=1}^{\infty}A_{j}\subseteq\bigcap_{j=1}^{n}A_{j}$
for each $n$ so that $\mu\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^{\infty}A_{j}\right)\leq\mu\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^{n}A_{j}\right)$
for each $n$.

Then $\mu\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^{\infty}A_{j}\right)>0$
would contradict what just has been proved, and we conclude that: $$\mu\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^{\infty}A_{j}\right)=0$$

Comment: that totally makes sense, thank you so much.